# Make plain HTML webpage look good on HiDPI and normal screens

Tags: html, retina-display

I've noticed on my **4k-monitor** that fonts look good, but a lot of images on websites look blurry using `Chrome` or `Firefox`.

How to make a `HTML` webpage (maybe with trivial `JavaScript`) look nice on all monitors, e.g. by providing two images :

**1.** For normal monitors (100%) and

**2.** For HiDPI monitors (200%)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quick and simple solution is to use just one image, larger than required.
For example:

There are downsides:

1. More data transferred and longer download times
2. Some older browsers might render not-exact-size images blurry

There are more sophosticated solutions with multiple images, they generally require additional javascript code and libraries. With just a few, easily compressable images, this solution could be smaller in download time still.

Comment: That I already had in mind, but remembered the ugly downsize rendering.

Comment: I have not seen any problems with downsizing, unless on Windows xp + Internet Explorer 8. Our company site uses this simple downsizing: [link](https://www.data-norms.cz/)

Comment: OK, I'll give it a try.

Comment: Unfortunately, the downsizing on non-HiDPI monitors in Chrome/Firefox on Windows 7 and Windows 10 looks very ugly.